# FillSchema does not return PrimaryKey using mySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, primary-key

I am trying to obtain the primary key of a table from a MySQL database.  When I use the MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver, the code below works fine.  When I change the code to use MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver, it does not work.  I've also tried the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver.  Anyone know why I cannot obtain the Primary Key of the table using the latest version of the MySQL ODBC Driver?

This code works and returns the PrimaryKey in the DataTable:

```
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=IP_Address;Database=DB_Name;User=username;Password=password;Option=3;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using(OdbcCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI';";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM \"items\"";
                using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adapter.FillSchema(dt,SchemaType.Source);
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
```

This code does not work - no PrimaryKey returned in the DataTable:

```
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=IP_Address;Database=DB_Name;User=username;Password=password;Option=3;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using(OdbcCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI';";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM \"items\"";
                using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adapter.FillSchema(dt,SchemaType.Source);
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
```